# Google Play Console reports InflateException without further details, only on some LG models: how go deeper?

Tags: android, crash, console

My app is very simple and shows an Android Map on main Activity. It works perfectly on several Phones and Tablets (not from LG) that I own.

Google Play Console reports the following Exception mostly on some LG devices and only on Android 6.0:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:401)
  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2171)
  at com.mdc.nasoni.mdcNasoni.onCreate(mdcNasoni.java:125)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
```

Layout is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/log"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FF0000" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mapcontainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonSave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/button01"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonCancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/button03"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonLayers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_layers"
        android:onClick="layersButtonClicked" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/splashTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/title_background"
        android:drawableBottom="@drawable/icon"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/cross" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/anchor"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nasoneGreen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/anchor"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/nasone_green" 
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the `onCreate()` in the main Activity:

```
/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}
```

I cannot see in the crash report any detail on what is causing it: any suggestion on how I could go deeper?

Thank you,

Max

UPDATE

It seems solved replacing

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

with

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
```

Comment: For More Details Put your MainActivity File code, Because Exception is at setContentView method.

Comment: I included the onCreate function, even if I don't think it adds any info. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to post your update as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

It seems solved replacing

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

with

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
```